# Sigining certificate error Xcode 8.3 to upper

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8.2

In Xcode 8.3 to upper i have an error to signing certificate
This is my error:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olwze.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo2u9.jpg)

What's the problem?

Comment: Make sure your provisioning profiles are valid and not expired?.

Comment: are you trying to run in device or simulator ?

Comment: Try with reboot your system. check KeyChain Access & delete old ,expired certificates.If nothing works , use ApplicationLoadeder for uploading ipa.This issue seems to be widely reported on Apple forums.

Comment: possibly Apple server is down , you can  try to reconnect later.

Comment: yes it work on simulator but not work in device and it is not expired